# ¿En cúal contexto se puede usar la forma «gustar de»?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

He visto rara vez el uso de «gustar de» en vez de la forma más común de «gustarle algo a alguien».

Por ejemplo:

- [Él] parece gustar de su obra tanto como de su propia vida.

¿Es correcta y entendida en todos lados?

¿Por qué eligirías usar esta forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según [el DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/gustar), se puede usar en todos los contextos en los que significa "causar placer o atracción" (negritas mías):

> Cuando significa ‘causar, o sentir, placer o atracción’ es intransitivo y puede construirse de dos formas:
>
> a) El sujeto es la causa del placer o la atracción, y la persona que lo siente se expresa mediante un complemento indirecto: «*Vos me gustás mucho*» (Rovner *Pareja* [Arg. 1976]); «*Le gustaban la buena música y los buenos libros*» (Palou *Carne* [Esp. 1975]). **Esta es la construcción normal en el habla corriente.**
>
> b) La persona que siente el placer es el sujeto y aquello que lo causa se expresa mediante un complemento introducido por *de*: «*Gustaba de reunirse con amigos en su casa*» (UPietri *Oficio* [Ven. 1976]). **Es construcción documentada sobre todo en la lengua escrita.** Debe evitarse la omisión de la preposición *de*, frecuente cuando el complemento regido es un infinitivo: ❌«*Barcelona y Tenerife, dos conjuntos que gustan jugar al ataque*» (*Vanguardia* [Esp.] 22.3.94).

Según el DPD, la construcción con complemento indirecto es la más común en la lengua hablada, y la construcción con la preposición *de* se encuentra sobre todo en la lengua escrita.

En cuanto a la pregunta sobre si es "entendida en todos lados", mi experiencia es que *gustar de* aparece con cierta frecuencia en la literatura, por lo que yo diría que sí.